# how to force system to present health data permission settings screen

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm working on Apple Health integration for my app. At some point, I call this code

```
HKHealthStore().authorizationStatus(for: )
```

to ask for user permission to read health data. The trouble is that system only displays the settings page once. After user has seen the screen, the call will simply return immediately. Even if I uninstall the app and install it again, I'll not get to see the settings screen.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to test if my app behaves correctly when system displays the settings screen. I suspect there is an issue as I'm getting weird reports from Crashlytics.

Is there for example an XCode build parameter which would allow me to test how will the app behave on a device which never saw this app before?

Thanks a lot

[image: Apple Health permission settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in the question will check the writing permissions but not request them.

This will ask for permissions:

```
healthStore.requestAuthorization(
        toShare: setOfWriteTypes,
        read: setOfReadTypes
    ) { (success, error) in
        
    }
```

The completion block's success will tell you that the permission screen was showed. It is showed only once during the whole time of the app's existence on the device.

If you want to enable permissions by the end user again after just closing the window or denying permissions, you need to tell it somehow to the user, that the user should go to the Apple Health App and manually select permissions to read/write.

In addition, you can not check, that the user granted reading permissions. Apple does not allow it with the current API. Only permissions for writing are allowed to be checked (your code snippet does the check).
As a workaround to understand if the user granted the reading permission, you can simply query steps (or other desired type) and see if there is any data in the snapshot, if there is no, then probably the user has declined reading permission or does not have data at all.

Btw. If you want, you can check out my CocoaPod https://cocoapods.org/pods/HealthKitReporter. It is a wrapper above HealthKit framework to make reading/writing easier.